# JavaScript accordion effect won't work, something to do with pseudoclass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml, pseudo-class

I tried to make an accordion effect with JavaScript based off this video altering a few things like using an input button instead of a link for the selector. However for some reason it's not working. Firefox error console outputs `unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element "visible"` every time I try to use it. What's the problem?

```
$("div.example").hide();
$("input.exampleButton").click(function(){
    $("div.example:visible").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown("slow");
    //return false; if you don't want the link to follow
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
input type="button" value="See An Example" class="exampleButton" />
<div class="example">
    ...content
</div>
input type="button" value="See An Example" class="exampleButton" />
<div class="example">
    ...content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the warning in the console. The reason the code is not working is that the markup structure doesn't match the traversal done by the Javascript. Each `<input>` should probably be inside a `<div>`, so that the call to `parent().next()` will correctly go from the input to the `<div class="example">` following it. You're also missing the opening `<` on the inputs but I assume that's a copy/paste error.

Working markup:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="See An Example" class="exampleButton" />
</div>
<div class="example">
    ...content
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="See An Example" class="exampleButton" />
</div>
<div class="example">
    ...content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there a way I could do it without the div and somehow change the JavaScript only? I'm not quite fundamentally understanding why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Dennis: You can remove the call to `parent()`. Then `next()` will go from the `<input>` to the element following it.